# Oracle sql random number by seed

Tags: java, sql, oracle, random

Is there way to generate random number with some seed?

```
SELECT  DBMS_RANDOM.value FROM dual;
```

Here code in java which fit my purposes

```
Random r1 = new Random(47);
        Random r2 = new Random(47);
        System.out.println(r1.nextInt());
        System.out.println(r2.nextInt());
        System.out.println(r1.nextInt());
        System.out.println(r2.nextInt());
```

here result

```
-1172028779
-1172028779
1717241110
1717241110
```

If i will run this code again and again i'll get the same result. Is there any way to do like this in Oracle sql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for the `DBMS_RANDOM` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_random.htm#ARPLS040) describes the `SEED` procedure, which resets the seed for the current session.

> DBMS_RANDOM can be explicitly initialized, but does not need to be initialized before calling the random number generator. It will automatically initialize with the date, user ID, and process ID if no explicit initialization is performed.
>
> If this package is seeded twice with the same seed, then accessed in the same way, it will produce the same results in both cases.
>
> In some cases, such as when testing, you may want the sequence of random numbers to be the same on every run. In that case, you seed the generator with a constant value by calling one of the overloads of DBMS_RANDOM.SEED. To produce different output for every run, simply to omit the call to "Seed" and the system will choose a suitable seed for you.

To demonstrate:

```
exec dbms_random.seed(47);

anonymous block completed

select dbms_random.value from dual;

     VALUE
----------
  .5976804 

select dbms_random.value from dual;

     VALUE
----------
.329618924 

-- reset
exec dbms_random.seed(47);

anonymous block completed

select dbms_random.value from dual;

     VALUE
----------
  .5976804 

select dbms_random.value from dual;

     VALUE
----------
.329618924
```

You can't call a procedure from SQL, you have to use a PL/SQL block (which is all `execute` is). You could, if you really need to, create your own wrapper function:

```
create function my_random_value(p_seed in number default null)
return number is
begin
  if p_seed is not null then
    dbms_random.seed(p_seed);
  end if;
  return dbms_random.value;
end;
/
```

Then call that with or without a seed:

```
select my_random_value(47) from dual;

MY_RANDOM_VALUE(47)
-------------------
           .5976804 

select my_random_value from dual;

MY_RANDOM_VALUE
---------------
     .329618924
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. First block of code fit my purposes. It did't work because I tried to call `exec dbms_random.seed(47)` but in jdbc sql statements I have to call `{call dbms_random.seed(47)}`

Comment: @ОлександрСамсонов - yes, `exec` is SQL*PLus shorthand for an anonymous block, so JDBC wouldn't understand that. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle `DBMS_RANDOM` package has a function called [`SEED`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i996798) which resets the seed to a value which you can define.

Comment: How it can bee used in sql not in pl/sql block?

Comment: @ОлександрСамсонов see the answer from Alex

Answer (score 1):

According to

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm
  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i996798

you should use

```
  DBMS_RANDOM.SEED
```

To set a seed. You can create a *function* to implement Random Generator with *seed*:

```
  create or replace function RandomGen(Seed NUMBER default null) return number is
  begin
    if (Seed is not null) then 
      DBMS_RANDOM.Seed(Seed);
    end if;  

    return DBMS_RANDOM.Value;
  end RandomGen;

    ...

  select RandomGen(123) -- <- Seed 123
    from Dual;

  ...

  select RandomGen -- <- No seed
    from Dual;
```